# Updating `ObservableArray` Item which is in json format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have Kendo `ObservableArray`, I am adding json values to this array.

```
var array = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
array.bind("change", function(e) 
{
    console.log("action: ["+e.action+"]  index:["+e.index+"] items:["+e.items+"]");

    // Do some calculations and then: 
    // 1. Set the calculated result to "result" variable
    // 2. Update "isDone" value to "true"

});

for(var index=0;index<5; index++)
{
    var object = new Object();
    object.name = "XYZ:"+index;
    object.id = index;
    object.isDone = false;
    object.result = 0;

    array.push(object);  
}
```

I am observing changes to this array, and once any I get event for item added to array, then I do some calculations/processing.

Once after processing I want to update values for newly added object.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good way to change items content in Kendo UI observable object or array is to use "set" method. To get the content use the "get" method.

```
array[0].set("name", "new name");
```

Check example here:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ADAHi

Also check the documentation from Telerik Kendo UI site to get the idea;

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#methods-set

> set
>   Sets the value of the specified field.

PARAMETERS
name String
The name of the field whose value is going to be returned.

value Number |String |Date |Object
The new value of the field.

Comment: Thanks for dojo and explanation, it really helped.